# Daily check all webpages from a list of websites

Tags: web-crawler, link-checking

A guest has a website **A** has a partner program.
Partner sites **B** have links to **A**.
I need to check with a certain frequency (twice a day) all webpages of all the partner sites (5000 sites) and extract all the links from **B** to **A**. Then I have to check with a regexp  if the url is built in a certain way.

I could easily do this with PHP, but there are some serious challanges that maybe a third party solution has already faced

- I want to leverage bandwith usage
- I want the task to be done the fastest possible
- The webpages to check could amateurs web pages full of errors and inconsistent html
- I'd like to manage only webpages that are changed since the last time I checked them
- the process has to be automated (cron? or alternatives?)
- ...
- (feel free to expand this list)

But I don't want to build a *super-duper-mega-ultra-sophisticated-that-does-everithing-and-more-tool*...
I'd stille like to have a small and lightweight clever solution.

How would you solve a task like this?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  - I want to leverage bandwith usage
>  - I want the task to be done the fastest possible
>  - The webpages to check could amateurs web pages full of errors and inconsistent html
>  - I'd like to manage only webpages that are changed since the last time I checked them the process has to be automated (cron? or alternatives?)
>  - (feel free to expand this list)
> ```

Those are some pretty hefty requirements.

> ```
> But I don't want to build a *super-duper-mega-ultra-sophisticated-that-does-everithing-and-more-tool*...
> ```

Oh, well, no problem then... now that you said that, I think we've narrowed it down to a *super-duper-mega-ultra-sophisticated-that-does-everithing-and-more-tool* that's **NOT** a *super-duper-mega-ultra-sophisticated-that-does-everithing-and-more-tool*.

Jokes aside, there are not a whole lot of tools that are capable of doing what you described. However, there are some pretty robust tools out there that might provide you a good framework for you achieve your goals. You mentioned PHP, but I think that you're going to have more success in the Java world. In particular, I would recommend that you check out [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/).

- It allows you to control your bandwidth usage via the configuration options.
- It's one of the fastest open-source crawlers (if not the fastest).
- It's good at [reading bad HTML](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-1.2/org/apache/nutch/parse/html/HtmlParser.html) (to the extent that it's possible).
- Nutch is pretty good at efficiently selecting pages that need to be crawled because it does implement the OPIC algorithm, however [the task of focusing on freshness is quite challenging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029822/how-can-i-bring-google-like-recrawling-in-my-applicationweb-or-console/9099798#9099798). You may have to [write your own plugin](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-1.4/index.html) to get more fine-grained freshness focus.

I hope that helps :).

Comment: :) when i said a _super-duper-mega-ultra-sophisticated-that-does-everithing-and-more-tool_ i was thinking to Nutch. Ok I understand that my requirements could need a robust tool like Nutch. 

I'll play with it during the weekend... thanks